# Angular unexpected behaviour. Self-executing function calls scope function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

[Working code sample.](https://jsfiddle.net/2t68undy/)

Trivial markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="APP">
<head></head>
<body ng-controller="myController">

    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Trivial code sample:

```
angular.module('APP', []).controller('myController', function($scope) {

    $scope.test = function() {
        console.log('Weird behaviour!')
    }

    (function() {} ()); //if you comment self-executing function console will be empty

});
```

And really strange scope behaviour. Can you please explain why this happens?

Comment: I am sure you know this javascript-specific code-style... here is an example: jsfiddle.net/prfy9eso . It is interesting to note that interpreting for that example works in a different way (blank lines change code behaviour in the second example, but do not change behaviour in the angular example).

Comment: 'return' [is a known exception](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return#Automatic_Semicolon_Insertion). Notice the note on "unreachable code after return statement", it concerns only Firefox, but using properly configured linter may prevent both situations.

Comment: Also `throw`, `continue`, `break`. [spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've unintentionally made `test` scope method IIFE, and the current code is essentially

```
$scope.test = (function() {
    console.log('Weird behaviour!')
})(undefined)
```

While `$scope.test` itself will be `undefined`.

It should be

```
$scope.test = function() {
    console.log('Weird behaviour!')
};

(function() {} ());
```

Semicolons are precious.

Comment: Well explained estus..appreciated +1

Comment: @PankajParkar, thanks, the answers appeared almost simultaneously.

Comment: but yours is better than mine ;)

Answer (score 4):

As you added code write after `$scope.test` function, It has `()` to it. So because of that it is `test` function is considered as `self` executing `function`,

As @estus already said you could avoid that issue by ending your function code by `;`.

**Code**

```
$scope.test = function() {
    console.log('Weird behaviour!')
}(function() {} ())
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answer for semicolon-haters:

```
 $scope.test = function() {
   console.log('Weird behaviour!')
 }

 !function(){}();
```

It's general rule to escape your startline `[`/`(`'s when you write semicolon-less style:

```
;[].forEach.apply(arguments, iterator)
;(function(){})()
```